# Binding Linq Query with Aggregates to ListView WPF C#

Tags: c#, sql, wpf, linq, xaml

I have a class "TimePunch" that records in/out time pairings for each user as well as a Flag level, which inherits from INotify and has a number of fluff public get/returns that will be left out for simplicity.

```
{
    private int ID;
    private string UserID = App.Username;
    private DateTime TimeIn;
    private DateTime TimeOut;
    private int Flag = 0; //0 = None, 1 = Manual, 2 = Edited, 3 = Unlikely, -1 = Deleted
    private string Notes;
...
```

I bind a collection of these as my underlying source for a listview and have a number of buttons that act like tabs to allow the Manager to switch which day of the week they're looking at and there's a control for changing the weekending date and filtering per user. Ok, everything's fine and dandy.

What I want to do is have a second listView bound to a query that shows a sort of "Overview" of the data source by summing up the hours worked per employee each day. (TimePunch's myHoursView returns a decimal of hours between TimeIn/TimeOut)

In SQL, the pseudo code I'm looking for would look something like:

```
SELECT UserID, 
MAX(FlagView) As Flag, --'FlagView' ignores -1 or deleted records
SUM(CASE WHEN myTimeIn.DayofWeek = DayofWeek.Monday
    THEN myHoursView Else 0 END) As Monday, 
SUM(CASE WHEN myTimeIn.DayofWeek = DayofWeek.Tuesday  
    THEN myHoursView Else 0 END) As Tuesday,
...
SUM(myHoursView) As Total  
FROM PunchList  
WHERE TimeIn > WeekEnding.AddDays(-7) AND
   <= WeekEnding 
GROUP BY UserID
```

Is there a way to cleanly do this in LINQ?

(Entity Framework is out of the question--mainly for compatibility)

Comment: EF is out, but are you saying no database interaction, or just don't use EF? Also is all the data available locally in the instances you mention and just need to be summed up?

Comment: I'm making use of an Azure SQL deployment which does not play nicely with Entity Framework. Instead I have written a custom class to handle all connections and exchanges. Relevant database records are downloaded and cached locally as Object Collections, which in theory I'm supposed to be able to manipulate with LINQ in a similar fashion as I would their source records with SQL... 

My main problem is with the syntax, as attempts I've made so far just output lists of lists, which then require additional C# coding and merging to get the output desired...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you want something like this:

```
var result = yourlist.GroupBy(
                 item => item.UserId,
                 item => item.UserId,
                 (key, items) => new { UserId = key,
                                       flag = items.Any(x => x.flag),
                                       monday = items.Where(x => x.DayOfWeek == monday).Sum(x => x.myHoursView), 
 // etc.
```

Comment: Took a bit of time to get the time to hammer it all out, but this worked beautifully and assisted my understanding of the syntax of LINQ. granted item.UserID was on there twice. Thanks!! :)

Comment: @BlackHatCS yw -- glad it was helpful.

Answer (score 0):

This recommendation is to instead use ADO.Net and call a Stored Procedure which has been setup to return JSON from Azure/SQL Server. Then deserialize the JSON returned from the sproc into structures/instances and then bind to the proper listview.

1. Create a stored procedure in Azure DB and return the proper DTO/Model via the `For JSON Auto` at the end of the select.
2. Run the sproc and extract an example of the JSON data.
3. Go to [JSON2CSharp](http://json2csharp.com/) and paste in the JSON to create a DTO object.
4. Put the class into your project.
5. Put in the call to the sproc in your project. An example can be found here on this .Net core Nuget Page ([SQLJSONReader](https://www.nuget.org/packages/SQLJSONReader/1.1.0#)). The page
6. The reader on that project can be found [SQLExtensions.cs](https://github.com/CheetahChrome/SQLJSONReader/blob/master/SQLJSONReader/SQLExtensions.cs) and it can be copied into your .Net code with no problems. *I wrote the Nuget Package/code and haven't created a .Net version yet*).
7. Note you can use Microsoft's `XmlReader` but it barfs on JSON escapes and cannot handle a data return of 2033 characters.
8. The example returns a `string` which will be the raw JSON. That will be need to be deserialized into your List.

With that done you can call your sproc, get the right data and bind that data as such.